# Spring Cloud Dataflow on Kubernetes - Startupprobe property

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

Am trying to setup SCDF on kubernetes using the helm chart
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow/README.md

Am able to get this working and deploy streams. Question i have is on the startupprobe path which my containers require. By default it is taking in info endpoint on actuator, instead i would like it to use actuator/health/liveness.

But i dont seem to have a property that I can set it at skipper (deployer) level. I do have the liveness and readiness probe path available and able to configure it.

spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.readinessProbePath
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.livenessProbePath

but am able to set as part of deployment, by using property
deployer..kubernetes.startupProbePath

Thou, this solution works, i would have to touch scripts of existing app to add this property, so it would help if there is a default at skipper level similar to readiness and liveness path?

I did try

spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.startupProbePath

didnt work for me.

Comment: startupHttpProbePath, helped get over it